# EF5 code first migrations navigating inside nested hierarchy

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

Database is genereated using code first migrations.

I have a parent child relationship like this, each Person has children and childrens may have their own children etc.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Flagged { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> Children { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Master { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

What is the most efficient way of finding these things? So far I have been using **recursive queries** and it seems slow and not a good thing to do. I read about **Common Table Expressions**, but I am not sure if this suits for my needs and supports EF **code first migrations**.

1. Person finds the first Master that has Flagged = true.
2. Person finds all nested children.
3. Person finds all nested children that has Flagged = true.

Comment: If these are common queries, I'd probably change the database structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK Entity framework does not support Common Table Expressions. You should probably go on with a database view. For me queries for getting parents and children looked like this.

```sql
    WITH Children AS 
 (
  SELECT a.*
  FROM dbo.Persons a
  WHERE Id = 14
  UNION ALL
  SELECT a.*
  FROM dbo.Persons a JOIN Children c ON a.IdParentPerson = c.id
  )
  SELECT *
  FROM Children 
  /*WHERE Children.Flagged = true*/ /*IF REQUIRED*/
```

and

```
    WITH Parents AS 
 (
  SELECT a.*
  FROM dbo.Persons a
  WHERE Id = 16
  UNION ALL
  SELECT a.*
  FROM dbo.Persons a JOIN Parents c ON a.Id = c.IdParentPerson
  )
  SELECT *
  FROM Parents
  WHERE Parents.Flagged = true
```

and then use it over a DbSet like

```cs
var id = YOUR_ID;
using(var context = new Context())
{
    var query = context.Set<GroupEntity>().SqlQuery(
    " WITH Parents AS  " +
    " ( " +
    " SELECT a.* " +
    " FROM dbo.Persons a " +
    " WHERE Id = @Id " +
    " UNION ALL " +
    " SELECT a.* " +
    " FROM dbo.Persons a JOIN Parents c ON a.Id = c.IdParentPerson " +
    " ) " +
    " SELECT * " +
    " FROM Parents " +
    " WHERE Parents.Flagged = true "
    , new SqlParameter("@Id", id));  
}
```

Comment: Yes, this works nicely for children and parents, but how would I select the first parent, that has `Flagged` = true

Comment: I've updated the answer. From that queries, you can then just pick first, with `TOP(1)`.

Comment: How can I integrate this to Entityframework? I mean, can I have something like a method or property that works like `Person.Children()` and then this stored procedure is called?

Comment: Such queries I execute as strings, `var results = DbSet<PersonEntity>.SqlQuery(*YOUR PARAMETRIZED AND SANITIZED QUERY*);`

Comment: Then I could not use it inside LINQ to Entities. How could I do the second query, and as a result return a list of 2 columns: personId, flaggedParentId.